# Google Cloud Storage - Bucket objects disappeared

Tags: google-cloud-storage

We have been using Google Cloud Storage for months and today all objects within this bucket just disappeared.

Is there anything we can do to recover the files? What is the best way we can contact Google?

PS: the bucket has no Lifecycle rules in order to automatically delete files.

UPDATE: we have managed to get a backup and found an issue on our end that could lead to an empty bucket. Thanks a lot for the object versioning suggestion, we are going to add this as well.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Open a support ticket. https://cloud.google.com/support-hub

Comment: Did you check the activity logs? Is it a wrong click?

Comment: We have managed to get a backup and found an issue on our end that could lead to an empty bucket. Thanks a lot for the object versioning suggestion, we are going to add this as well.

Comment: Can you share the nature of there issue you found?  I have also experienced this where the bucket is randomly emptied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google cloud storage supports [object versioning](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/object-versioning), which would allow you to view/rollback previous versions of objects uploaded to the bucket. However, unless this was explicitly enabled there would be no way of recovering deleted files.

This is extremely strange behaviour. As mentioned in the comments please go through the activity logs in your google cloud console and check to see if an admin user accidentally deleted the files in your bucket.

If you can't find any sign of user interaction, open a support ticket with google support as soon as possible and mark it as urgent to escalate it as quick as possible.